# tproxy configure with connbytes

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, iptables, transparentproxy

I have a transparent proxy.
I want to redirect a `rdp` connection to local process, but from 3rd packet. that means I want to pass first and second packet and from **3rd packet until end** redirect packets to local process.
I use code below to configure my tproxy.
But it does not work and no packets pass and no packets go to local process(50082).
Could you please help me? I don't know my mistake.

```
${ip} rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
${ip} route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100

${iptables} -t mangle -N DIVERT
${iptables} -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
${iptables} -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
${iptables} -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT

${iptables} -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -m connbytes --connbytes 3: --connbytes-dir both --connbytes-mode packets -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 50082  

${iptables} -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -m connbytes --connbytes 1:3 --connbytes-dir both --connbytes-mode packets  -j ACCEPT
```